# Different code behaviour on localhost and Azure Cloud Services. Why?

Tags: php, azure, localhost

I have a project that works flawlessly on localhost but as soon as I run the same project on Azure Cloud Services, many features like emoticon rendering, date rendering and hyperlink rendering become inconsistent. Anyone knows why and how I could fix this problem?

The whole project is in PHP, HTML 5, CSS and JavaScript.

Comment: What do you mean? The code should behave same server side, isn't it?

Comment: while your code is the same all the software running it, all the settings are probably not. There is no global fix for any differences you need to look at each of your problems and fix them individually.

Comment: You've really not given us much to go on. I'd suggest editing your question, giving specific errors you're seeing. Just saying your app has "become inconsistent" doesn't help.

Comment: Sorry about not giving details. Should have included screenshots. I managed to fix 3/4 problems. 

The problem of incorrect date/time rendering was because the Azure server was selected as North Europe and so it was the time difference problem between that of London and North Europe. SO we fixed that.

The problem of incorrect hyperlink rendering and the string not being printed sometimes was because I was using addSlashes($tweetText) instead of addslashes($tweetText).

The problem of emoticon rendering still exists (runs fine on localhost but not on Azure), trying to fix that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so there were 4 problems and all are sorted out:

- Incorrect date/time rendering : The location of Azure server and where I currently am had a time difference which resulted in this problem.
- Empty boxes and incorrect hyperlink rendering : The PHP in-built function addslashes was incorrectly referred to as addSlashes. Also, assigning a PHP variable to a JavaScript variable needed multiple-line string handling in JavaScript.
- Incorrect emoticon rendering : The PHP version on Azure Server was chosen 5.4 instead of 5.6 .

Sorry for not giving enough info about the errors but all the problems are now sorted out. Will post questions in a more meaningful manner in the future. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

agree with most except "Empty boxes and incorrect hyperlink rendering : The PHP in-built function addslashes was incorrectly referred to as addSlashes". 
Ans:
the reason was multi-line strings passing between js and php and handling " ' \ correctly while transferring variables between these two languages
and also conforming to the way twemoji.parse() expects emoticons to be represented in a string
\uXXXX not \u or sth else.